# How can i add animation to materialize pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I have 3 html files in my code. at this moment, I use a tag as `a` link and I want to add animation for the page switching.

I am using `materialize` but I can't find how to add animation for that.

Anyone can help?(I want when I click a button in my `index.html`, it will animate for example slide right, and change to `menu.html`)

This is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "Sources/bootstrap.css">

    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "Sources/Matirialize.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "Sources/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/Matirialize.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the menu.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p>this is supose to be the menu page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth slide transition between two separate html files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899278/smooth-slide-transition-between-two-separate-html-files)

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, you cannot create animations for transitions between two separate HTML pages, since the browser "gets rid" of the first page and stops all of its code before it begins to load the second page (and therefore, before its code begins to run). Basically, during the time between pages, you don't have the ability to run your own code to create animations.

If you look at the link לבני מלכה posted in the comments, however, you can see some ideas for getting around this by making the browser load the new page in special ways and then inserting it into the browser window (rather than just having an `a` link).